# How am I supposed to invoke clearApplicationUserData() in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

From the app context? Do I have to include a permission?

And does it close/reboot the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
private  fun clearAppData() {
        try {
            // clearing app data
            if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
                (getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager).clearApplicationUserData() // note: it has a return value!
            } else {
                val packageName = applicationContext.packageName
                val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
                runtime.exec("pm clear $packageName")
            }
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Note: This might kill/close your application after clearing user data

Comment: Looks like it works, but what if I want to reboot it after cleaning?

Comment: That you can do with the help of  'Intent'

Comment: How to synchronize it?

Comment: This just gives me a whole bunch of syntax errors